# Can't properly read a dictionary saved as json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am unable to properly read into a dataframe a dictionary that I save
 as a json file. The key seems to be corrupted. Not sure whether
 problem is with the usage of `json.dump()` or `pd.read_json()`.  I want
 the key to be the leftmost column but it seems to be mixed into a time
 datatype. I have the following dictionary:

```
t1 = {
    "666020888022790149": {
        "contributors": None,
        "coordinates":  None,
        "created_at": "Sun Nov 15 22:32:08 +0000 2015"},
    "666029285002620928": {
        "contributors": None,
        "coordinates": None,
        "created_at": "Sun Nov 15 23:05:30 +0000 2015"},
    "666033412701032449": {
        "contributors": None,
        "coordinates": None,
        "created_at": "Sun Nov 15 23:21:54 +0000 2015",
            }
}
```

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('test1', 'w') as f:  
    json.dump(t1, f,
              sort_keys = True,
              indent=4)

df = pd.read_json('test1',orient='index')
df.head(3)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `pd` is not defined.

Comment: `index` is type of `datetime64`. convert to `int64`: `df.index = df.index.astype(pd.np.int64)`

Comment: I could see this being useful if i have to force column conversion after using  "convert_axes=False" parameter. But are you saying that 'index' is by default interpreted as datetime64 datatype? May have missed it while looking at pandas docs.

Comment: yes, apparently happens if it's a big integer. what do you see if you do `df = pd.read_json('test1', orient='index')` and then check `df.index.dtype.__str__()`? me too I don't like this behavior of pandas. mentioned here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/io.html#data-conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell Pandas not to convert the axes:

```
result = pd.read_json('test1', orient='index', convert_axes=False)
#                    contributors  coordinates          created_at
#666020888022790149           NaN          NaN 2015-11-15 22:32:08
#666029285002620928           NaN          NaN 2015-11-15 23:05:30
#666033412701032449           NaN          NaN 2015-11-15 23:21:54
```

The index is of type string:

```
result.index.dtype
#dtype('O')
```

As a side note, 'test1' is a bad name for a CSV file. 'test1.csv' is much better.

Comment: Yes, this does work. But when i look at the saved file the key is in double quotes, implying it is a string. I was expecting it to be read in as a string also, not as a datetime datatype.

Comment: That's because pandas json reader is "too smart" and is trying to do some guessing for you, unless you tell it not to.

Comment: still you can convert to string if necessary: `df.index = df.index.astype('str')`

Comment: @deeenes The index _is_ of type string. (See the amended answer.)